# service fabric explorer requires ssl certificate?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I can connect to my service fabric cluster Explorer using my client certificate.

However, it seems to force SSL and my service fabric cluster does not have any DNS mapping for it's server certificate. So the browsers try to block it. Is there any way to not have SSL enabled for the explorer, since it's already using client certificate mutual auth?

Alternatively, if I have an internally load balanced service fabric cluster, is there any suggested way to give the server certificate some sort of real cert even though it has now DNS associated with it? It's only IP based of the internal LB.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need encryption to protect the [client authentication handshake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Client-authenticated_TLS_handshake).

The solution is to get a proper certificate. Use self-signed certificates for testing purposes only.

You can use something like [Azure Traffic Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-overview) to configure your custom domain name for the cluster, provided your cluster has a DNS name.